# Reopen and migrate question 396934

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

The following question was closed for being poorly written and off topic (strictly smart phone, iOS related):

https://superuser.com/questions/396934/how-can-i-paste-link-on-the-form-after-copying-a-link-from-twitter-ios-client

However, I was able to confirm that there is a real issue involved. So, after I tidy it up, I wish to reopen and migrate the question to Apple.SE.

Comment: `Mobile Safari` is what makes it off-topic, but I agree that upon improvement it could fit Apple.SE. Guess a mod can ask if they want it ... +1

Comment: @TomWijsman Mobile Safari is also off topic on Apple.SE?

Comment: No, I was just explaining the close reason for Super User; could be that you already knew that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for cleaning it up, I've migrated to [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange